# icu: Sort strings based on 2 different locales

Tags: python, sorting, locale, icu

As you probably know, the order of alphabet in some (maybe most) languages is different than their order in Unicode. That's why we may want to use `icu.Collator` to sort, like this Python example:

```
from icu import Collator, Locale
collator = Collator.createInstance(Locale("fa_IR.UTF-8"))
mylist.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)
```

This works perfectly for Persian strings. But it also sorts all Persian strings before all ASCII / English strings (which is the opposite of Unicode sort).

What if we want to sort ASCII before this given locale?

Or ideally, I want to sort by 2 or multiple locales. (For example give multiple `Locale` arguments to `Collator.createInstance`)

If we could tell `collator.getSortKey` to return empty bytes for other locales, then I could create a tuple of 2 `collator.getSortKey()` results, for example:

```
from icu import Collator, Locale

collator1 = Collator.createInstance(Locale("en_US.UTF-8"))
collator2 = Collator.createInstance(Locale("fa_IR.UTF-8"))

def sortKey(s):
    return collator1.getSortKey(s), collator2.getSortKey(s)

mylist.sort(key=sortKey)
```

But looks like `getSortKey` always returns non-empty bytes.

Comment: It would be much easier to test this if you included sample input and desired output to make it a complete [MRE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late to answer the question, but here it is for future reference.

ICU collation uses the CLDR Collation Algorithm, which is a tailoring of the Unicode Collation Algorithm. The default collation is referred to as the root collation. Don't think in terms of Locales having a set of collation rules, think more in terms of locales specify any differences between the collation rules that the locale needs and the root collation. CLDR takes a minimalist approach, you only need to include the minimal set of differences needed based on the root collation.

English uses the root locale. No tailorings. Persian on the other hand has a few rules needed to override certain aspects of the root collation.

As the question indicates, the Persian collation rules order Arabic characters before Latin characters. In the collation rule set for Persian there is a rule `[reorder Arab]`. This rule is what you need to override.

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use `icu.RuleBasedCollator` with a coustom set fo rules for Persian.
2. Create a standard Persian collation, retrieve the rules, strip out the reorder directive and then use modified rules with `icu.RuleBasedCollator`.
3. Create collator instance using a BCP-47 language tag, instead of a Locale identifier

There are other approaches as well, but the third is the simplest:

```
loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("fa-u-kr-latn-arab")
collator = Collator.createInstance(loc)
sorted(mylist, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

This will reorder the Persian collation rules, placing Latin script before Arabic script, then everything else afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

For ASCII-before-locale sorting, you can just check whether the string is ASCII:

```
def sortKey(s):
    """ASCII strings first"""
    return (not s.isascii()), collator.getSortKey(s)
```

For multiple languages, it is ambiguous for `icu`, e.x. is `"Dobrý večer"` string Czech or Slovak? Also, there are a lot of languages that have multiple ASCII-only words.

---

For python<3.7, use:

```
def is_not_ascii(s):
    return any(ord(c) > 128 for c in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell `collator.getSortKey()` to return empty bytes for other locales, but you can control the sorting behavior using a function that returns a tuple of the desired sort keys in the desired order.

```
def sort_key(s):
    return (collator1.getSortKey(s), collator2.getSortKey(s)) if s.isascii() else (collator2.getSortKey(s), collator1.getSortKey(s))

mylist.sort(key=sort_key)
```